# How can incorporate session variable in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, session

I want to incorporate a session variable `$_SESSION['LI']` into the jQuery with an if statement.
So `if($_SESSION['LI'] == 'falsus')` hide the #feedback else show #feedback.

Thanks

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['LI'] = 'falsus';
?><html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#feedback').hide();
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="feedback">Hello</div>
        <? print_r($_SESSION);?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you just do something like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['LI'] = 'falsus';
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <?php if($_SESSION['LI'] == 'falsus'): ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#feedback').hide();
                });
            </script>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="feedback">Hello</div>
        <? print_r($_SESSION);?>
    </body>
</html>
```

This will only add the script to hide the #feedback div when the session variable is `"falsus"`. If it is NOT `"falsus"`, then the whole script block is omitted.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['LI'] = 'falsus';
?><html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
<?php if ($_SESSION['LI'] == 'falsus') { ?>
        $('#feedback').hide();
<?php } else { ?>
$('#feedback').show();
<?php } ?>
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="feedback">Hello</div>
    <? print_r($_SESSION);?>
</body>
</html>
```

You can weave your code with php wherever you want.